# React native socket.io is server_error

Tags: react-native, sockets, socket.io

Hi everyone I'm trying to use socket.io. I installed it to server and I can send recieve message with simple js in webbrowser

```
<body>
  <div class="mesaj">

  </div>
  <script>
    const socket = io('http://.net:3000');
    socket.on("connect", () => {
      console.log(socket.connected); 
    });


    socket.on('message', function(data) {
      var message = '<div>sendUser: '+data.sendUserId+' - message: ' + data.message+'</div>';
      console.log(message);
      $('.message').append(message);
    });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I just want to use it form react-native app. here's my code

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

componentDidMount() {
    const socket = io('http://:3000');
    socket.connect();

    socket.on('connect', (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
    socket.on('onOpen', (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });

    socket.on('message', function (data) {
      var message =
        '<div>sendUser: ' +
        data.sendUserId +
        ' - message: ' +
        data.message +
        '</div>';
      console.log(message);
    });
    socket.on('connect_error', (err) => {
      console.log('socket error', err);
      socket.connect();
    });
}
```

It always stuck in `connect_error` and it says server error
[the screenshot][1]

What should I do . Thank you

When I connect echo server`('wss://echo.websocket.org/')` in socketio it works but not on our server. Our server is socket 2 but my react native socket version 4.0.1
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqgQu.png

Comment: Hello, your variable socket only exists when you are running componentDidMount.

Comment: Okay then where should I put theese codes